# Javascript RegExp parse URL make hyperlinks ignore img src

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not very good with Regular Expressions, some times I can figure them out but...

I need to parse text strings (for a chat room project).

So as you would imagine any pasted URLs need to be converted to click-able hyper links.

I use this RegExp for that, cobbled together from examples I have found on the net.  It appears to work quite well :

```
/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:~;@'#%&.=\]\[\*\$\!\?\/\,]+/g
```

Now another part of my project has to insert images in other words :

```
<img src="http://path/to/image" alt="alt" />
```

So I need the reg exp to ignore those, and I tried this :

```
/(?!src=")[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:~;@'#%&.=\]\[\*\$\!\?\/\,]+/g
```

But it doesn't work.  Perhaps my expression is faulty or I am going about it the wrong way.

I may just mask out 'src="http' and run my expression then reapply what I masked out.

But before I do that I thought I would see if anyone here has any ideas.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm still unsure what you're trying to do. Where will the images be inserted and what is the regex you've written supposed to do?

Comment: This regex looks like you just blindly copy-pasted from the one above.  I would read up on javascript RegExp and play around with this. http://regexpal.com/

Comment: The first expression identifies urls and I later use it to make those urls into hyper links.  There are no images to be inserted using the expression, as I said I want to ignore already encoded images. If you look carefully you will see that the second expression has (?!src=") at the beginning...

Comment: Tronbabylove, it appears you blindly commented without taking a good look ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?!src=")
```

is a negative **lookahead**, what you want there is a **lookbehind**, which javascript does not support.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks, at least I learnt something new today.  I will use my masking idea then.  Thanks for your reply :)